# How can I build a version tagged in Mercurial with Hudson?

Tags: mercurial, build, tags, hudson

I'm using Hudson to build my project from my Mercurial repository. There are two jobs: One builds the tip, the other should build the latest release. When I tag a release and then use that tag in the field "branch", I get this error:

```
[workspace] $ hg update --clean --rev Release_1_2_beta1
abort: unknown revision 'Release_1_2_beta1'!
```

When I run the same command in my local copy, it works. It also works when I clone the  What could be the reason that it breaks on Hudson?

Comment: You might be better asking this on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing you're doing is inherently wrong, but I have a guess based on how mercurial tags are tracked.  Is it possible that you're cloning into that workspace using `--rev` too?

This pattern of commands doesn't work:

```
% hg init test

% echo this > test/file

% hg -R test commit --addremove --message 'a commit'
adding file

% hg -R test tag mytag

% hg clone --rev mytag test test-clone

% hg -R test-clone update --rev mytag
abort: unknown revision 'mytag'!
```

The reason that doesn't work is the `clone --rev` brings over all the changesets up to and including the one pointed to by the tag `mytag`, but it doesn't bring over the subsequent changeset that actually creates a tag named `mytag`.

If that's the problem (and again it's just a guess) then you either need to clone over everything or `hg update` to `tip`.

If that's not the case look in your `.hgtags` file and verify that tag exists in it.

Comment: I see no `hg clone`. What I see in the logs is `hg incoming -r mytag`. Could that lead to the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Up until today the Mercurial plugin of Jenkins (Hudson) does not support [tags](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5396).

One approach which work for me is configuring the 'default' Branch in the job and configure a 'windows command' or 'shell script' as first build step which executes:
`hg update -r TAGNAME`